# Are there any solutions to this congruence system

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $p,q_i,i=1,2,..m$ be odd primes with integer $m>2$

Does this system of congruences have any solutions?

$\prod_{i=1}^m(q_i-1)\equiv2(p^2)$

$\prod_{i=1}^mq_i\equiv2(p^3)$

Comment: As stated, the congruences are either true or false depending on the given numbers. What quantities do you intend to be varied so that "are there any solutions" can be asked?

Answer (score 3):

We can even get the first congruence hold modulo $p^3$ as well.

For example, $m=3$, $p=5$, $q_1=67$, $q_2=367$, and $q_3=743$.